# My Bitcoin client has stopped syncing

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, synchronization

[image: bitcoin-qt]

As you can see my client is stuck on 99,7% with `unknown. Syncing Headers(577895)`, It has been in this state since last day synced(which you can see). How can I get it to work since I have plenty of disk space and I run a computer maintenance program quite often.

Comment: Can you include the contents of the debug.log file?

Comment: Contents of debug.log:
`2019-06-08T07:51:14Z Potential stale tip detected, will try using extra outbound peer (last tip update: 230677 seconds ago)
2019-06-08T07:51:20Z New outbound peer connected: version: 70015, blocks=579781, peer=8097
2019-06-08T08:01:09Z Timeout downloading headers from peer=8084, disconnecting
2019-06-08T08:01:09Z ERROR: AcceptBlockHeader: block 0000000000000000000267fdf54d391d7e63d24c92f9437f94897fbc0c63c1e1 is marked invalid
2019-06-08T08:01:10Z ERROR: AcceptBlockHeader: block 0000000000000000000267fdf54d391d7e63d24c92f9437f94897fbc0c63c1e1 is marked invalid`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the lower right corner of your "Bitcoin Core - Wallet" window where you see icons of `BTC`, a lock icon, `HD`, and two more to the right. The icon on the right to the `HD` shows how many nodes you are connected to. And, it seems like your node is not connected to any peers.

There might be two causes of this:

1. Your node is not connected to the internet.
2. There are no other bitcoin nodes available at that specific moment.

For these two problems, you should check and make sure you are connected to the internet, and wait for your node to pick up on other peers on the network.